# How do you Echo Data?

Tags: assembly, 68000

Is there a way to echo DATA in 6800 assembly?

If I have it stored like this:

```
DATA    DC.W      1,2,3,9,8,7
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no universally correct answer to your question.  When writing assembly code, doing output is dependent on the configuration of your machine.  you might have a terminal attached to a serial UART chip that you can write a character to on an IO port, or a memory-mapped register, or you might have an LCD display with an interface library, or a memory-mapped video display where you have to compute the X/Y coordinates of your strings as memory addresses.

Without more details than "6800 assembly" no one will be able to answer you.

(Also, you said 6800 but tagged this question 68000; they are quite different.  Doesn't change my answer, though.)

Comment: Im using Easy68k, I just want to print that info to the screen.

Comment: If you go look at the easy68k.com site, the very first example code shows how to do Hello World.